# RIA Service's method always returns null. How to resolve it?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a RIA Service and I need to use some of the methods in a silverlight app.
Here is how the sample RIA Service's method looks like:

```
    [Invoke]
    public string TestService()
    {
        return "good!";
    }
```

And here is one of the ways how I tried to use it in a silverlight app:

```
           var ctx = new MyDomainContext();


           public string str;
           ctx.TestService( (i) =>
           {
               if (!i.HasError)
               {
                    str= (string)i.Value;

               }
           }, null);
```

And for some strange reason I always get `null`;
Please advise.

Comment: "always get null" meaning that `i.Value` is always `null` when you check it with a breakpoint?

Comment: A couple more things to note: RIA should give a type in the `Value` property, so you should't need to cast to `string` if it's compiling properly; also, have you checked your code as written here? Because it works fine.

Comment: Yes, "always get null" means i.value is always null. I used several types to test: string, a custom type, etc and it's always null.

Comment: Is this caused by the InvokeAttribute? According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.invokeattribute%28v=vs.91%29.aspx): Even when an invoke operation returns an entity, the entity is generated for the client project only if it is returned by a query method. Can you post the generated (.g.cs) proxy? Andy.

Answer (score 1):

str must be global not variable

```
private string Str { get; set; }
```